# Show digits of Number, even when it is 0 (input:12 output:12.00)

Tags: c#, numbers

Hey is there is simple way to show 12 as 12.00, when I convert it to string?
I can't just add zeros, cause it also has inputs with digits, where only one 0 need to be added.

Some inputs and there espected outputs:

```
12    ->    12.00 
1.3   ->    1.30
0.2   ->    0.2
3.454 ->    3.45
```

I have tried this:

`String.Format("{0:0.00}", Regex.Replace(VerkaufspreisInput.Text, 12);`

Output 12

It's the wrong function.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Why `0.2` and not `0.20`? And what's the type of the input "numbers"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ToString` with `N2`, e.g.:

```cs
Console.WriteLine((12.00).ToString("N2"));
```

Will print `12.00`.

Comment: That's it. Thank you verry much.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're close, but you need to change the second part of your String.Format (the format specifier).

Try changing `{0:0.00}` to `{0:F2}`

For reference, here is the documentation for format specifiers for numbers:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings